# How to mock (or) test a method level variable in Android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I have a class something like this,

```
class MyIntentProvider {
    public Intent provideIntent(final Context context) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        final List<ResolveInfo> matchedServices = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(intent, 0);

        if(matchedServices.size() == 1) {
            String packageName = info.serviceInfo.packageName;
            String serviceName = info.serviceInfo.name;
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, serviceName));
        }
        return intent;
    }
}
```

and my test class looks like this,

```
class MyIntentProviderTest {

  @Mock
  private Context mContext;
  @Mock
  private PackageManager mockPackageManager;
  @Mock
  private Intent mockIntent;
  @Mock
  private ResolveInfo resolveInfo;
  private List<ResolveInfo> mockResolvedInfoList;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        myIntentProvider = new MyIntentProvider();  
        mockResolvedInfoList = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
        mockResolvedInfoList.add(new ResolveInfo());  
    }

    @Test
    public void provideIntent() {

        //setup
        mContext = spy(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
        doReturn(mockResolvedInfoList).when(mockPackageManager).queryIntentServices(any(Intent.class), anyInt());

        //test
        final Intent intent = myIntentProvider.provideBindingIntent(mContext);

        //verify
        assertNotNull(intent.getComponent());
    }
}
```

But  always the size of `matchedServices` returns 0. How to mock this?

Comment: What is `mockResolvedInfoList`?

Comment: Edited the post. It's just a member variable @CommonsWare

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't see how you are tying `mockPackageManager` to `mContext`.

Comment: I'm trying this way. I'm new to unit testing. I'm not sure this is how i should do it :(

Comment: I do not know about the rest of your code or test, but I would mock the `Context` and have it return `mockPackageManager` in response to `getPackageManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding anything to the list so it will always return 0. You have two options, either get a list with some data or stub it like so.

```
doReturn(1).when(mockPackageManager).queryIntentServices(any(Intent.class), anyInt()).size();
```

Then do your verify or assert stuff after you call your method, which you did correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modifying your `MyIntentProvider` class to make it more testable. In other words, creating a variable that provides `matchedServices` instead of getting it from another class. Your class may look like the following.

```
public class MyIntentProvider {

    private List<Service> matchedServices; 
    private Info info;

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Info getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }

    public List<Service> getMatchedServices() {
        return this.matchedServices;
    }

    public void setMatchedServices(List<Service> matchedServices) {
        this.matchedServices = matchedServices; 
    }

    public Intent provideIntent(final Context context) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        final List<ResolveInfo> matchedServices = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(intent, 0);

        if(matchedServices != null && matchedServices.size() == 1) {
            String packageName = info.serviceInfo.packageName;
            String serviceName = info.serviceInfo.name;
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, serviceName));
        }
        return intent;
    }
}
```

Once you have set up the class like above, it becomes easier to write tests for the class. You really do not have to mock the instance, if you do not have to.

```
public class MyIntentProviderTest {

    private MyIntentProvider myIntentProvider;
    private Info dummyInfo;
    private List<Service> dummyMatchedServices;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        myIntentProvider = new MyIntentProvider();  
        dummyInfo = new Info();
        dummyMatchedServices = getDummyMatchedServices(); // Just return a dummy list as per your need

        // Now set it here 
        myIntentProvider.setInfo(dummyInfo);
        myIntentProvider.setMatchedServices(dummyMatchedServices);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        myIntentProvider = null;
        dummyInfo = null;
        dummyMatchedServices = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testHere() {
        // Do the testing here
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.